# Is there a way to check if a turtle is touching a color?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am tryng to make a game with edge walls and inner walls but I don't know how to sense if the turtle is touching the inner wall(the outer wall checks turtles position and moves him back). My outer wall code is this:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
if t.xcor() >= 425:
        t.setx(424)
    if t.xcor() <= -425:
        t.setx(-424)
    if t.ycor() >= 375:
        t.sety(374)
    if t.ycor() <= -350:
        t.sety(-349)
```

and my walls should look like this:
[image: in the middle of the turtle screen]

in the center of turtle screen

Comment: Please provide more information of what you want to achieve, such as data structures being used, screenshots and code examples

Comment: Does the turtle move on the green parts or the white parts?

Comment: White parts green are walls.

Comment: @Psychzander Do you want me to improve my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your graph is something like this:
[image]

Here is how:

```
if -350 < turtle.xcor() < 350 and -325 < turtle.ycor() < 325: # For A
    if turtle.xcor() >= 350:
        turtle.setx(349)
    if turtle.xcor() <= -350 and (25 < turtle.ycor() < 325 or -25 > turtle.ycor() > -325):
        turtle.setx(-349)
    if turtle.ycor() >= 325:
        turtle.sety(324)
    if turtle.ycor() <= -325:
        turtle.sety(-324)

if -25 < turtle.ycor() < 25 and -425 < turtle.xcor() < -350: # For B
    if turtle.ycor() > 25:
        turtle.sety(24)
    if turtle.ycor() < -25:
        turtle.sety(-24)
```

Comment: You mean everything's size divided by 5?

Comment: Does that mean the problem's solved, or do you need me to update the post?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the coordinates of the turtle on the screen and see if they are at or past the coordinates of the wall.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer an approach that initially has higher overhead than the already suggested answer, but in the long run will be simpler as it'll be easier to reconfigure your walls without having to redo *all* your calculations.

The approach is to make the walls out of *stamps*, i.e. define a basic brick that is a turtle and construct your walls by stamping out bricks and keeping track of their positions.  We can then use coordinate comparison collision detection to make sure we're inside the window, but as far as the innner and outer walls, we can use turtle's `distance()` method:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Vec2D
from random import randrange

BRICK_SIZE = 75
WIDTH, HEIGHT = BRICK_SIZE * 9, BRICK_SIZE * 9
CURSOR_SIZE = 20
EXPLORER_COUNT = 10
EXPLORER_SIZE = BRICK_SIZE / 3.75
CHROME = 14  # window overhead, e.g. borders

def draw_wall(brick):
    wall = []

    brick.goto(-WIDTH/2 + 3 * BRICK_SIZE/2, -HEIGHT/2 + 3 * BRICK_SIZE/2)

    for delta in [Vec2D(1, 0), Vec2D(0, 1), Vec2D(-1, 0), Vec2D(0, -1)]:
        for index in range(6):
            if not (index == 3 and delta == (0, -1)):
                brick.stamp()
                wall.append(brick.position())

            brick.goto(brick.position() + delta * BRICK_SIZE)

    return wall  # a list of brick positions

def collision(t):
    if any(t.distance(brick) < BRICK_SIZE * 2**0.5/2 for brick in wall):
        return True

    x, y = t.position()

    width = screen.window_width()

    if not EXPLORER_SIZE/2 - width/2 < x < width/2 - EXPLORER_SIZE/2:
        return True

    height = screen.window_height()

    if not EXPLORER_SIZE/2 - height/2 < y < height/2 - EXPLORER_SIZE/2:
        return True

    return False

def move():
    for explorer in explorers:
        while True:
            explorer.forward(1)

            if not collision(explorer):
                break

            explorer.undo()
            explorer.setheading(randrange(360))

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move, 10)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH + CHROME, HEIGHT + CHROME)
screen.screensize(100, 100)  # just to accommodate smaller windows
screen.tracer(False)

brick = Turtle()
brick.hideturtle()
brick.shape('square')
brick.shapesize(BRICK_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
brick.color('green')
brick.penup()

wall = draw_wall(brick)

explorers = []

for _ in range(EXPLORER_COUNT):
    explorer = Turtle()
    explorer.shape('turtle')
    explorer.shapesize(BRICK_SIZE / 3.75 / CURSOR_SIZE)
    explorer.color('red', 'pink')
    explorer.setheading(randrange(360))
    explorer.penup()

    explorers.append(explorer)

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it supposed to be that changing the `CURSOR_SIZE` will only change the appearance, not the way the turtles collide with the walls?

Comment: No, @AnnZen, `CURSOR_SIZE` is a fixed constant that roughly converts the arguments to `shapesize()` from relative dimensions to pixels.  Pondering the OP's "divided by 5" comment, I've gone back and tweaked my code to make everything relative to `BRICK_SIZE` so it's now scalable.  Though it runs fine at `BRICK_SIZE = 15`, it looks kind of silly at that scale, as it also speeds up a bit.

Comment: I open it with file explorer so you can steer the player and... I will edit the top to show the image.

Comment: My problem is, if you go out the hole in the wall and go up or down, it pushes you back in. On IDLE you can't steer.

Comment: @Psychzander, your question was basically about collision detection against walls.  Anything beyond that is for you to work out, or ask a new question.