# How can I make turtle check for color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, python-turtle

Say I had a turtle moving forward until it touches black, and if it does, it turns by 90 degrees. How would I go about programming this in python? How can I make turtle check for a certain color?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to check if a turtle is touching a color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623928/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-turtle-is-touching-a-color)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe python-turtle has color detection, instead another way you can try is to stop and turn 90 degrees when the turtle has moved forward for a certain amount.

Similar stackoverflow question:
(["Is there a way to check if turtle is touching a color?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62623928/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-turtle-is-touching-a-color))